# ListView with header [Android]

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list and I would like to add a 'header'.

I've tried this [tutorial](http://anishantha87.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/how-to-create-custom-listview-in.html) and my code final is :

```
 ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista_producto);

    // URL to the JSON data         
    String strUrl = "http://server/file.php";

    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data 
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

    // Starting the download process
    downloadTask.execute(strUrl);

    // Getting a reference to ListView of activity_main

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaJson); 
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    mListView.addHeaderView(header);
    /*View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    mListView.addHeaderView(header);*/

}

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
        }

        return data;
    }



    /** AsyncTask to download json data */
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
        String data = null;
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
                        try{
                            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);

                        }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
                        }
                        return data;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                        // The parsing of the xml data is done in a non-ui thread 
                        ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();
                        // Start parsing xml data
                        listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);   
                }
    }

    /** AsyncTask to parse json data and load ListView */
    private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{

        JSONObject jObject;
        // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread 
        @Override
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
                JSONParser DealJsonParser = new JSONParser();
                DealJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("JSON Exception1",e.toString());
            }

            // Instantiating json parser class
            JSONParser DealJsonParser = new JSONParser();

            // A list object to store the parsed countries list
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> deal = null;

            try{
                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                deal = DealJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }          

            // Keys used in Hashmap 
            String[] from = { "nombre","flag","details","precionuevo","descripcion",};

            // Ids of views in listview_layout
            int[] to = { R.id.price,R.id.dealimage,R.id.details,R.id.price,R.id.descripcion};

            // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
            // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item         
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), deal, R.layout.list_view, from, to);  

            return adapter;
        }

        /** Invoked by the Android on "doInBackground" is executed */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

            // Setting adapter for the listview
            /* AÑADIR HEADER?
            View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
            mListView.addHeaderView(header);
            */

            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
                String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
                ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

                HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put("flag_path",imgUrl);
                hm.put("position", i);

                // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview 
                imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
            }

            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                          String URL = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descripcion)).getText().toString();//this will take the value of the invincible textView
                            Intent i = new Intent(Lista_productos.this, pruebalista.class);
                            i.putExtra("URL", URL);
                            startActivity(i); 
                          }      
        });
    }

    /** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
    private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

            InputStream iStream=null;
            String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
            int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(imgUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url                
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                // Getting Caching directory 
                File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                // Temporary file to store the downloaded image 
                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");               

                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);             

                // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);              

                // Flush the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.flush();

                //Close the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.close();             

                // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
                HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                hmBitmap.put("flag",tmpFile.getPath());

                // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                hmBitmap.put("position",position);              

                // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
                return hmBitmap;                


            }catch (Exception e) {              
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
            // Getting the path to the downloaded image
            String path = (String) result.get("flag");          

            // Getting the position of the downloaded image
            int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

            // Getting adapter of the listview
            SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) mListView.getAdapter();

            // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);   

            // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter 
            hm.put("flag",path);

            // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            /*Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Lista_productos.this, path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();*/
        }   
    }
    }
```

When you run the application prints the list and the header but after 6 seconds, the app quits unexpectedly showing errors in logcat:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uj1a3zj64wrtzfy/error3.png

Comment: There is ClassCastException in your onPostExecute Method. Can you please share that method.

Comment: @Homosapiens Edited, This is my full code.